# How do I combine two numpy arrays based on the first Element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got one arrays with four data points:

```
Array = np.array(["type1", 1, 2, 3], ["type2", 3, 4, 1], ["type1", 0.5, 0.5, 1], ["type2", 1, 1, 0.5])
```

I want to combine the four data points based on their types and calculate the mean of the three numbers.  So that it looks like this:

```
Array = np.array(["type1", 0.5, 1, 1.5],["type2", 1.5, 2, 0.5])
```

I tried some functions of numpy but I always get erros, or not the intended results.

How do I combine the four data points based on their type (1 or 2) and calculate the mean of the numbers?

Comment: Bad idea to mix types in a numpy array. Try to find another representation or go for standard python lists

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called pandas that would actually help you with this. Numpy is not good for operations based on strings.

```
import pandas as pd 
m = pd.DataFrame([["type1", 1, 2, 3], ["type2", 3, 4, 1], ["type1", 0.5, 0.5, 1], ["type2", 1, 1, 0.5]])
arr = m.groupby([0],as_index=False).mean().values
```

Output of `arr`

```
array([['type1', 0.75, 1.25, 2.0],
       ['type2', 2.0, 2.5, 0.75]], dtype=object)
```